# How to set javafx datepicker value correctly?

Tags: java, javafx

I used this method to setting `DatePicker` value:

```
public static final LocalDate LOCAL_DATE (String dateString){
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy");
    LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse(dateString, formatter);
    return localDate;
}

try {
    datePicker.setValue(LOCAL_DATE("2016-05-01");
} catch (NullPointerException e) {}
```

But sometimes throw an exception:

> java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '' could not be parsed at index 0

So what's the wrong here?

Comment: You specify a pattern of "dd-MM-yyyy" and provide "2016-05-01", which clearly doesn't match that pattern.

Comment: this is a formatter  for datepicker.

Comment: Well yes, obviously, but the point is that you are providing the date in a different format to the one you specify for the formatter.

Comment: I have tried without any DateTimeFormatter once!

Comment: does this formatter to tell datepicker the value or to show?

Comment: In the code you posted, the formatter has nothing to do with the date picker at all. You just use it for parsing a string to a `LocalDate`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You specify a format for parsing the date of `dd-MM-yyyy`:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy");
```

but then you provide the date in a format that doesn't match that:

```
datePicker.setValue(LOCAL_DATE("2016-05-01"));
```

Obviously, `"2016-05-01"` is not in the format `"dd-MM-yyyy"`.

Try

```
datePicker.setValue(LOCAL_DATE("01-05-2016"));
```

Answer (score -2):

For people who found this answer while trying to learn how to set the date picker to today:

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
datePicker.setValue(LocalDate.now());
```